# Why is Vue/JS variable only set/correct after logging it to the console first?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a very simple Vue JS single file component and in it's mounted hook, I am trying to get the offsetTop of one of the elements (using refs):

```
mounted () {
  let vm = this
  // console.log(vm.$refs.ttb.$el.offsetTop)
  let navOffset = vm.$refs.ttb.$el.offsetTop
  console.log(navOffset)
}
```

If I uncomment the 2nd line and log the value to the console it's correct in both log outputs (127 in our case). However with the 2nd line commented out, it's always 0. Any thoughts on why?

Here is the template. It a bit complex because were pulling in an image and using a Vue UI framework called [Quasar](https://quasar-framework.org/components/layout.html):

```
<template>
  <q-layout view="hhh Lpr lFf">
    <q-layout-header>
      <div class="primary">
        <img
          class="center responsive"
          alt="banner"
          src="http://someserver/api/banner"
        />
      </div>
      <q-toolbar ref="ttb"  //HERE IS THE TTB REF
        color="primary"
        :inverted="$q.theme === 'ios'"
      >
        <q-btn
          flat
          dense
          round
          @click="leftDrawerOpen = !leftDrawerOpen"
          aria-label="Menu"
        >
          <q-icon name="menu" />
          <q-tooltip>
            Main Menu
          </q-tooltip>
        </q-btn>
        <q-toolbar-title class="flex flex-center">
          My Title
          <!--<div slot="subtitle">Powered by ePapers</div>-->
        </q-toolbar-title>
        <q-btn flat round dense icon="fas fa-user">
          <q-tooltip>
            Account
          </q-tooltip>
        </q-btn>
      </q-toolbar>

    </q-layout-header>

    <q-layout-drawer
      v-model="leftDrawerOpen"
      :content-class="$q.theme === 'mat' ? 'bg-grey-2' : null"
    >
      <q-list
        no-border
        link
        inset-delimiter
      >
        <q-list-header>Essential Links</q-list-header>
        <q-item @click.native="openURL('http://quasar-framework.org')">
          <q-item-side icon="school" />
          <q-item-main label="Docs" sublabel="quasar-framework.org" />
        </q-item>
        <q-item @click.native="openURL('https://github.com/quasarframework/')">
          <q-item-side icon="code" />
          <q-item-main label="GitHub" sublabel="github.com/quasarframework" />
        </q-item>
        <q-item @click.native="openURL('https://discord.gg/5TDhbDg')">
          <q-item-side icon="chat" />
          <q-item-main label="Discord Chat Channel" sublabel="https://discord.gg/5TDhbDg" />
        </q-item>
        <q-item @click.native="openURL('http://forum.quasar-framework.org')">
          <q-item-side icon="record_voice_over" />
          <q-item-main label="Forum" sublabel="forum.quasar-framework.org" />
        </q-item>
        <q-item @click.native="openURL('https://twitter.com/quasarframework')">
          <q-item-side icon="rss feed" />
          <q-item-main label="Twitter" sublabel="@quasarframework" />
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-layout-drawer>

    <q-page-container>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>
```

UPDATE: OK we've isolated this down a bit, but still do not have a final solution. It seems that is we remove the banner image, this works as expected. So, we are assuming the http in the img src is async and moving the ttb ref element down after completion and AFTER we have gotten it's offset. Any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: I have tried with your case. It's working fine. May I have a look of your template and ttb component

Answer (score 0):

OK - we figured this out and here is what we did. We moved the check for the scroll position to a method called from the img load event:

```
<div class="banner">
  <!-- MOVED CHECK TO getScroll METHOD CALL FROM IMG LOAD -->
  <img
    @load="setScroll"
    class="center responsive"
    alt="banner"
     src="http://localhost:8000/api/apec2018/banner"
   />
 </div>
```

Then in that method, the scrollPos is correct:

```
methods: {
  getScroll () {
    let h = document.getElementById('ttb')
    let scrollPos = h.offsetTop
    console.log(scrollPos)
  }
}
```